# Find files beginning with string and remove X characters from filename Powershell

Tags: powershell, rename

I've looked around and googled for a solution, but nothing seems to do what I'm looking for.

I have 40 or so files that arrive every day with a datetime string at the start of the filename that i need to remove.

The format of the files is:
**YYYYMMDD_HHMM_filenametokeep.csv**

I'd like to first look for files in a folder that start with 20 (as thats the start of the YYYY in the filename) and then rename any files it finds by removing the first 14 characters from those filenames.

Ideally I'd like to do this in powershell so I can put it as a step in a SQL job.

Does anyone have any ideas/solutions for this?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: What if "filenametokeep" is the same for multiple files - should it be overwritten?

Comment: Hi, sorry i should've mentioned it will never be the same. Every file will have a different ending. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Ls d:\path\to\folder\20*.csv | ren -new { $_.name -replace '^.+?_.+?_' }
```

Or you can also use:

```
Ls d:\path\to\folder\20*.csv | ren -new { $_.name -replace '^.{14}' }
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I specify a folder to run this in?

Comment: So I've used this script, and changed **20*.csv** to **D:\path\to\folder\20*.csv** and it finds and removes the characters that I need but it also removes the file extension. How do i keep the file extension? Thanks

Comment: @user2992750 Instead of `.Basename` you could use `.Name`. Not sure yet how that will affect your regex

Answer (score 0):

If you truely intend just to remove the first 14 characters you can do that as well with `.SubString`

```
Get-ChildItem D:\path\to\folder\20*.csv | ForEach-Object{ 
    Rename-Item -Path $_ -NewName ($_.Name.SubString($_.Name.Length -14))}
```

This [TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176945.aspx) talks about `.Substring` being used like the VBS `Right` method. It will return a string minus the first 14 characters.